# Make a nn.Module faster

Tags: python, torch

I have a nn.Module (CRAFT from clovaai) and I am a bit bothered because the prediction is quite long (~13s) on my CPU.
Is there general tips (other than taking a GPU) to improve the prediction with such networks ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Pruning

You should look into "model pruning". It's a general concept in the field for which there are a number of tools and techniques.

The basic idea is that large networks can often be pretty "sparse", meaning that the majority of the weights are not contributing very much to the final output. As such, you can remove them and observe fairly little degradation in performance. Removing weights from the network reduces its size and therefore also how much work inference requires.

#### Reducing precision

This I am less familiar with in practice, but the idea is that if you reduce the "precision" (i.e. bit-depth) of the computations at runtime, you can similarly trade accuracy (or really, precision) for speed in inference.